# How do I exclude blank cells when trying to count unique values separated by commas for multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm trying to come up with a formula that will count unique values separated by commas for multiple cells and count the blank cells as 0.

Example:

`X2; 875  Y2; 575,628  Z2; Blank`   Should equal 3 but is returning 4.  Its counting the blank cell as 1.

Here is the formula I have put together:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(X2:Z2)-LEN( SUBSTITUTE(X2:Z2,",",""))+1))
```

What do I need to add to account for the blank cells?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a condition to exclude blank cells. For instance:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(X2:Z2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(X2:Z2,",",""))+1,--(X2:Z2<>""))
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  When I use that formula it returns #Value! instead of a number.  What is causing that?

Comment: I'm not able to recreate that. Step through your formula with the `Evaluate Formula` tool on the `Formula` ribbon and see which part generates the error.

Comment: I was able to correct it and am now getting the correct value.  Thank you so much for your help.